# Blender units vs metric

Tags: export, 3d-printing, units

I just started getting into 3d printing. At first I scaled my models down to a few cm tall in blender, but found them nearly microscopic at print time. After some fiddling with netfab, it seems like 1m/1bu = 1mm in print world. Is it common practice to keep the model in bu and let the printer software scale the object? Could this be an .stl export setting I missed? Is there a way to match the two environments consistently? Thanks!

Comment: I would keep it as-is rather than making a near microscopic model in Blender, as decimal rounding may make your model less accurate than it would be if you made it larger in Blender.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Inside Blender, 1 Blender Unit equals 1 meter, however, when importing, the software you are using could perceive arbitrary units as being equal to something other than 1 meter.

There are a couple of ways to solve this problem:

### 1. Change the Scene's scale factor

To do so, go to the Properties panel, then under the Scene tab, find the Units subsection and change the Scale field.

[image]

When set to 1, 1BU = 1m, but if set to 10, 1BU = 10m; Pretty straight forward.

### 2. Change the exporter's scale factor

To do this, when exporting to `.stl`, before hitting `Export`, you can change the scale field, located on the bottom left corner.

[image]

### 3. Scale the object up in Blender

Hit <kbd>S</kbd> and the enter your scale factor/ratio, for instance `10`, and the object will be 10 times bigger.

### 4. Scale the object up in the printing software

You figure that out.

Answer (score 0):

On the right, "Scene" menu (icon has a cylinder, a sphere and a lamp) go to "units" / "unit represents" and choose your units of measure.  I usually work in "millimeters".  Cura slices it and scales it the way I want.